# signedRequest not working for liked field anymore

Tags: facebook-like

While developing facebook apps I want to fetch the liked status of a page to redirect them accordingly.Earlier I used the following code:

```
<?php 
require 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "**************";
$app_secret = "*************************************";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

if($like_status==1)
echo "liked";
else 
echo "not liked";
?>
```

But due to the new policy by facebook, in the apps developed after 7th aug 2014 I cannot get the page liked status using this method.
Pages.isFan() is also not working and FQL I read will not last long. Is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Fangates are dead, they don´t work for new Apps anymore, and there is no other way to do it. They also forbid them in the Platform Policy (see Changelog):

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a
>   Page.

That is why the like value in `signed_request` was removed.